# Prtscr key recognized as Audio Media key

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, shortcut-keys

So i have Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel v.4.17.14. This problem appears around a week ago. When i press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>- opens default system media player and takes a screenshot. I thought that it's shortcut in VLC but it isn't. Uninstalled VLC- now RhythmBox opens when I press the key. Updated kernel to v.4.18- did not help.

In settings <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key was set to copy screenshot to clipboard.

Reseting all shortcut settings did not help either.
When trying to set new shortcut and press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key it's recognized as Audio Media key. I do not know what to do, any ideas?

[image: Prntscr recognized as Audio Media in keyboard settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was that i modified grub file and added to the line **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** string **i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd**
After i removed it, updated my grub and reboot everything works fine.

P.S. This string was suggested as a fix of bug when after suspend my keyboard was not responding sometimes.